# Fetch abstract type data from plist

Tags: plist

I have archived JSON data in plist as data abstract type.
My plist format is :

```
`<dict>
    <key>
        <array>
            <data> 
                4352ght4 qwe435g5 yu67k10p
            </data>
        </array>
    </key>
    <key>
        <array>
            <data>
                4352ght4 qwe435g5 yu67k10p
            </data>
        </array>
    </key>
    <key>
       <array>
            <data>
                4352ght4 qwe435g5 yu67k10p
            </data>
        </array>
    </key>
</dict>`
```

This data type contains long JSON entries. How do I fetch data from this property list and display them in the table.
I have also prepared .h and .m classes to fetch data.

Comment: Removed unhelpful flags.  Improved formatting.  Tightened wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSString *plistFilePath  = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"plist.plist"];

```
NSDictionary *list = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];
NSLog(@"%@",list);

for (id key in list) {
    NSArray *array = [list objectForKey:key];
    timesheetObject *timeobject = [timesheetObject alloc];
    for(int i=0;i<array.count ;i++)
    {

        timeobject = (timesheetObject *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog(@"%d",timeobject.taskId);
       NSLog(@"Start time %@",timeobject.startTime_actual);
    NSLog(@"End Time %@",timeobject.endTime_actual);
    [self.objectHolderArray addObject:timeobject];
```